# Mutiple time intervals on week days - best method to store in db and process

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database-design, calendar

I am working on a project where I need to combine multiple time slots on the week days to result the effective time slot.

See the example below

Time slot1 = **sun**, mon, tue, **wed**, **thu**, fri, sat   09:00 to 17:00
Time slot2 = sun, **mon**, tue, **wed**, thu, **fri**, sat   18:00 to 23:00

Time interval doesn't apply on days mark in **bold**.

Effective Time Slot =

```
Sun 18:00 to 23:00  
Mon 09:00 to 17:00  
Tue 09:00 to 17:00 and 18:00 to 23:00  
Wed No access  
Thu 18:00 to 23:00  
Fri 09:00 to 17:00  
Sat 09:00 to 17:00 and 18:00 to 23:00
```

How can I store that in a database in a way that would make it simple to understand and process?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: It's sql-server rdms. I've added the tag. Thanks

Comment: Timeslots (id, groupid,  weekday, startTime,  endTime)

Comment: Why would your example timeslots result in those effective timeslots?    Why "no access" on Wed?   Why two timeslots only on Tues and Sat?   I don't see any logic to what you're trying to do.

Comment: I need effective time slot to be inclusive of all possible times on particular day. In the above example, for Tue there are two separate time intervals that are not overlapping so in order to cover both the time slot's time, effective time slot for Tue will be 9 to 17 and 18 to 23.

Answer (score 0):

Tables structure for MS SQL 2008+

```
CREATE TABLE TimeSlots(
    id INT identity(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,groupId int
    );

CREATE TABLE TimeSlotItems(
    id INT identity(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,slotid INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TimeSlots(id)
    ,weekday VARCHAR(3)
    ,startTime TIME(0)
    ,endTime TIME(0)
    );

-- 2 slots of group 10
INSERT INTO TimeSlots(groupId)
  VALUES (10), (10); 

INSERT INTO TimeSlotItems(slotid,weekday,startTime,endTime)
  VALUES 
   (1, 'Sun', '09:00' ,'17:00')
  ,(1, 'Mon', '09:00' ,'17:00')
  --...
  ,(2, 'Sun', '18:00' ,'23:00')
  ,(2, 'Mon', '18:00' ,'23:00')
;

 SELECT s.groupId, i.* 
 FROM TimeSlotItems i
 JOIN TimeSlots s ON s.Id=i.slotid;
```

Comment: That's most obvious solution. Is there any other way that can save repeating time intervals for each days? If I go with this approach imagine the scenario when time slot's end time is updated , it will require all the days to update the end time in table which is quite inefficient.

Comment: This solution gives the flexibility to have different intervals for different weekdays. If there exist some rules which restrict this freedom please specify them. And please correct your question, does the upper/lower case has some special meaning (i guess so) ?